# Javascript / JQuery Custom Events - Is there a limitation on number of custom events that I can create on document object?

Tags: html, jquery, events, event-handling, dom-events

I have an application where there are 200+ sub components or templates, and each has its own JS to handle UI interactions.

The way the current application is designed is:
on the page load, all JS's of all the templates are loaded at one go *(This is a must for me, as there is dependency on minification and global functions that may be in use)*
, but with a caveat that, in each JS of the template, there is a $(document).ready and a condition to check if the template is part of the DOM, and if yes, then execute the JS.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   if($(".myTemplate1Class").length) {
      //initialize myTemplate1's JS code
   }
});
```

Note that: there are a lot of $(document).ready calls as many as the number of templates. And each call has a DOM traversal check.
I am worried that on the page load, due to the condition, there will be as many number of DOM traversals as the number of templates I have. And this may be having a negative impact on page load.

In order to reduce the number of DOM traversals, I plan to make slight changes:

1. have a single $(document).ready in a global JS.
2. in this, identify the templates that are part of DOM. ( i could probably use a unique class identifier for all my templates).
3. then trigger custom events corresponding to the the templates found say:
   $(document).trigger("myTemplate1ClassFound");
4. In each of my template js, instead of triggering the js on document.ready, i would execute it on this custom event.

```
 $(document).on("myTemplate1ClassFound", function(){
   //initialize my Template1's js code.
 });
```

I can see two advantages here,

1. better control over the sequence of which templates code get's executed first.
2. DOM traversal is only once.

The downside being, the number of custom events that I will end up creating.

Questions:

a. Is there any limitation on the number of custom events that can be created?

b. Any better approach that can be suggested?

For example, should i go for one parameterized custom event, instead of multiple custom events
`$(document).trigger("myTemplateLoaded", ["myTemplate1Class"]);`

Comment: *"should i go for one parameterized custom event"*: why not trigger that event on the DOM element concerned, instead of `document`?

Comment: @trincot, i dont have any common dom element. i may probably add a hidden element and trigger all the events with reference to it. But question is more on:, is there any limitation on the number custom events that i can create?

Comment: No, there's no limit on the number. jQuery doesn't have any fixed limits on anything.

Comment: JavaScript isn't C, there's no reason to declare fixed-size arrays. Everything just grows as needed.